# using OR in SQL statement

Tags: sql

I have an issue with my select statement; basically, it goes something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE colA LIKE '%test%' OR colA LIKE '%hold%' AND colb > 1
```

The colB does not evaluate unless I remove the `"OR colA LIKE '%hold%'"`.  Wondering how to make the OR apply only to the colA evaluation.  I realize I could make OR the last evaluation but wanted to understand how to better work with OR for future sql statements.

It does work if I put OR at end.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE colA LIKE '%test%' OR colA LIKE '%hold%' AND colb > 1
```

No errors occur; just can't evaluate anything after OR statement and sometimes need to employ OR when using wildcards

Comment: Add parentheses for the `OR` condition as `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (colA LIKE '%test%' OR colA LIKE '%hold%') AND colb > 1`.

Answer (score 0):

`AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`.  So as written, the condition breaks down into two independent clauses:

`colA LIKE '%test%'`

and

`colA LIKE '%hold%' AND colb > 1`

A row will be returned if it matches either of these clauses.

To get the result you want, use parentheses to group the conditions:

```
(colA LIKE '%test%' OR colA LIKE '%hold%') AND colb > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The command OR must be used with care because it can break all logic. It should generally be used in parentheses to configure the order of execution.

Example:

I want to select oranges or apples that cost more than $100:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM fruits
WHERE (name = 'orange' OR name = 'apple')
AND value > 100.
```